# Can we determine memory CAS Latency in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to ask if it is possible to even determine memory CAS Latency in Node.js, just like the title suggests. I have had no luck with searching the web and I am starting to believe it would not be possible. If it is possible, would anyone be kind enough to provide some explaination on how to determine or some documentation? Many thanks!

Comment: @Bergi Im sorry I already updated my question

Comment: @Bergi I meant the CAS Latency, Column Address Strobe Latency

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible to determine? How would you determine it if not using Node.js?

Comment: @Bergi I wasn't able to find any way of doing so, the only thing that came up when searching for the thing was nemory leak preventions which weren't even related to CAS latency at all.

Comment: What were you searching for? Don't search for turnkey solutions in nodejs specifically, search for *how* to measure this (independent of programming language) and then implement it yourself.

Comment: @Bergi I was hoping for an already existing module, but nvm then